# Неоднородные члены все же однородны или запятая между неоднородными членами предложения

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Имеем предложения:

1. Кто слышал эту новость?
   Здесь "кто"- вопросительное местоимение, выступающее в роли подлежащего.
2. Где вы нашли эти вещи, уважаемый?
   Здесь "где"- местоименное наречие, выступающее, по всей видимости, в качестве обстоятельства.
3. Где и когда вы в последний раз видели Сергея Семеновича?
   Здесь, наверное, аналогично пункту 2.
4. Кто, где и когда мог видеть вас в Париже?
   Здесь и возникает основной вопрос. Какую роль играют "кто", "где", и "когда"?
   Если "кто"-сказуемое, а "где" и "когда" - обстоятельства, то что позволяет нам ставить запятые?
   Возможно, неполные предложения. Или у них общая часть?

Comment: 1. Кто — подлежащее, слышал — сказуемое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пора начать диалог с самим собой!

Несомненно однородными являются компоненты, соединенные всеми сочинительными союзами, кроме союза И, который может соединять как однородные, так и неоднородные члены.

**Соединение неоднородных происходит в следующих случаях:**

- если соединяются вопросительные слова. Напр.: *КТО И КОГДА мог тебе это сказать?*
- если соединяются отрицательные слова. Напр.: *НИКТО И НИКОГДА не заставит меня сделать это.*
- если соединяются неопределенные слова. Напр.: *ГДЕ-НИБУДЬ и КОГДА-НИБУДЬ мы обязательно встретимся.*
- если соединяются слова со значением всеобщности. Напр.: *А поступают так ВСЕ И ВСЕГДА.*
- если соединяются одинаковые слова. Напр.: *Все о ТЕБЕ и для ТЕБЯ.*

Предложение может распространяться рядом словоформ, синтаксически не подчиненных друг другу и связанных между собой союзом и интонацией или только интонацией.

Связь словоформ, образующих ряд, называется сочинительной связью. Словоформы, составляющие ряд, обычно занимают в предложении одну и ту же синтаксическую позицию.
Такие словоформы, объединенные сочинительной связью, являются однородными членами предложения.

**Ряд может быть образован также словоформами, связанными с одним и тем же членом предложения, но занимающими разные синтаксические позиции.** Напр.: *НИКТО и НИКОГДА не узнает об этом. КОГДА и КАК построен Эрмитаж.*

Сочинительная связь ставит так называемые неоднородные члены в одинаковую синтаксическую позицию. **Члены ряда могут быть выражены местоимениями, при этом различие в их значении сочинительной связью устраняется.**

Еще примеры:

*Мы все учились понемногу чему-нибудь и как-нибудь. Где и в чем прообраз вашего движения вперед?*

Кажется, все так и есть, как изложено выше.